# i want to use filter in two js objects and want to filter id if exist in both with change in the xp parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, filter

i have 2 js array objects

oldarray having (id, name,xp)
newarray having (id,name,xp)

i want to use filter that if the id matches in both array object then push that data of that id in new finalArray with xp =(newarray.xp - oldarray-xp) how to to do that i have no idea

```
const myOldArray = [
{ "id": 1, "name": "A", "xp": 100 },
{ "id": 2, "name": "B", "xp": 150 },
{ "id": 3, "name": "C", "xp": 120 },
{ "id": 4, "name": "D", "xp": 70 },
{ "id": 5, "name": "E", "xp": 50 },
{ "id": 6, "name": "F", "xp": 100 }];

const myNewArray = [
{ "id": 1, "name": "A", "xp": 150 },
{ "id": 2, "name": "B", "xp": 200 },
{ "id": 3, "name": "C", "xp": 140 },
{ "id": 4, "name": "D", "xp": 100 },
{ "id": 5, "name": "E", "xp": 20 },
{ "id": 7, "name": "G", "xp": 50 }];
```

and the result array will built like id

- **id matches** then **xp will changed**
- if the id in **old not found** in new just **neglect** it
- if id in newarray found but not in old then **just push xp of newarray**

```
const finalArray = [
    { "id": 1, "name": "A", "xp": 50 },
    { "id": 2, "name": "B", "xp": 50 },
    { "id": 3, "name": "C", "xp": 20 },
    { "id": 4, "name": "D", "xp": 30 },
    { "id": 5, "name": "E", "xp": 30 },
    { "id": 7, "name": "G", "xp": 50 }];
```

can anyone help me how to do that

```
const finalArray= myOldArray.filter((el) => {
  return myNewArray.some((f) => {
     if(f.id === el.id)
    return el.xp-f.xp;
  
  });
});

console.log(finalArray);
```

Comment: You need Array.find() to look for a match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we can neglect extra id's from myOldArray, we can iterate over myNewArray.

What I did was:

1. Convert myOldArray to a dictionary of `{id:xp}` with `Array.reduce()`
2. Iterate over myNewArray with `forEach` and subtracting the xp values using the dict, or 0 if it's not found.

If you don't want to mutate myNewArray you can clone it with `const finalArray = [...myNewArray]` or use `myNewArray.map()`

```js
const myOldArray = [
{ "id": 1, "name": "A", "xp": 100 },
{ "id": 2, "name": "B", "xp": 150 },
{ "id": 3, "name": "C", "xp": 120 },
{ "id": 4, "name": "D", "xp": 70 },
{ "id": 5, "name": "E", "xp": 50 },
{ "id": 6, "name": "F", "xp": 100 }];

const myNewArray = [
{ "id": 1, "name": "A", "xp": 150 },
{ "id": 2, "name": "B", "xp": 200 },
{ "id": 3, "name": "C", "xp": 140 },
{ "id": 4, "name": "D", "xp": 100 },
{ "id": 5, "name": "E", "xp": 20 },
{ "id": 7, "name": "G", "xp": 50 }];

const oldXp = myOldArray.reduce((acc, obj) => ({...acc, [obj.id]:obj.xp}), {})
console.log('Dict: ', oldXp)

myNewArray.forEach(obj => obj.xp -= oldXp[obj.id] || 0)

console.log(myNewArray)
```

Here's an appraoch where we don't edit the old array:

```js
const myOldArray = [
{ "id": 1, "name": "A", "xp": 100 },
{ "id": 2, "name": "B", "xp": 150 },
{ "id": 3, "name": "C", "xp": 120 },
{ "id": 4, "name": "D", "xp": 70 },
{ "id": 5, "name": "E", "xp": 50 },
{ "id": 6, "name": "F", "xp": 100 }];

const myNewArray = [
{ "id": 1, "name": "A", "xp": 150 },
{ "id": 2, "name": "B", "xp": 200 },
{ "id": 3, "name": "C", "xp": 140 },
{ "id": 4, "name": "D", "xp": 100 },
{ "id": 5, "name": "E", "xp": 20 },
{ "id": 7, "name": "G", "xp": 50 }];

const oldXp = myOldArray.reduce((acc, obj) => ({...acc, [obj.id]:obj.xp}), {})

const finalArray = myNewArray.map(obj => {
  obj.xp -= oldXp[obj.id] || 0;
  return obj
})

console.log(finalArray)
```

Comment: how to push that data to result object. rather than update in mynewArray

Comment: Anytime :) I updated my answer with a method that makes a new array.